# puppeteer doesn't open a url without protocol

Tags: chromium, puppeteer, headless

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

This one works

```
await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

This doesn't work (without the protocol i.e http/https)

```
await page.goto("www.example.com');
```

It throws error

> Protocol error (Page.navigate): Cannot navigate to invalid URL

**Why doesn't it append the protocol like it does when we open in Google Chrome?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Google Chrome Omnibox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/omnibox/) (Address Bar) has built in functionality to handle multiple complexities, such as: appending protocols, autocomplete, etc.

Puppeteer provides an API to control Chrome or Chromium over the [DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/), so much of this functionality is currently out of the scope of Puppeteer.

The Puppeteer documentation for the function [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) explicitly states:

> The url should include scheme, e.g. `https://`.

This is because `page.goto()` utilizes [`Page.navigate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-navigate) from the Chrome DevTools Protocol.

The [Chromium source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/devtools/protocol/page_handler.cc?type=cs&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=428) shows that navigation via `Page.navigate` is explicitly checked for validity, and if the URL is not valid, it will return the error, "Cannot navigate to invalid URL."

You can easily create a function in Node.js that will append protocols to URLs, and that could be a workaround for your issue.

Comment: Thank you @grant, I missed the `page.goto()` doc line regarding scheme. Also, I ended up using NodeJS core package `url` (https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) to tackle this. Feel free to mentions this package in your last paragraph.

Comment: I posted this related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837950/puppeteer-doesnt-render-pages-with-images-urls-without-a-protocol-scheme.  Is there some way to use this page.navigate to catch where this occurs?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when I was sending the url as an array of arrays

```js
const urls = [["https://www.example1.com"], ["https://www.example2.com]]
```

destructuring it solved it for me

```js
urls = [].concat(...urls)
for(let url of urls) {
    await page.goto(url)
 }
```