# set browser profile settings via puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium, headless

I am using puppeteer to crawl sites, take screenshots and log all the set cookies.

Everything is working fine but only first party cookies are saved to the browser.
After some tweaking I found out that it is probably the setting in the attached picture that I have to change to "Allow all cookies".

I couldn't find any way to change the browser settings via puppeteer.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

[image: Settings in Chrome]

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(process.argv[2], {waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });

await page.screenshot({path: '1.png'});

const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
var content = await client.send('Network.getAllCookies');
var json = JSON.stringify(content, null, 4);
console.log( json );


var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("output.json", json, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
        return console.log(err);
    }       
    process.exit();
});


})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually the kind of settings that can be set on ***chrome://settings/cookies*** can be also set via chrome launch flags (they are listed [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)), but in case of "Allow all cookies" there seems to be no dedicated flag to do this. Navigating to ***chrome://settings/cookies*** and set it with puppeteer is neither an option (pages without a protocol cannot be visited with headless chrome due to a schema validity check, see [`page.goto`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) and more detailed explantion by Grant Miller [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101893/12412595)).

As your question's title already mentions it: you can use a dedicated chrome user profile (let's call it *AllowCookies*) that already has the required cookie settings. After this profile is created you have multiple ways to use it in puppeteer:

- either by using the `executablePath` and `userDataDir` options on [`puppeteer.launch`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions);
- or applying the `--user-data-dir=` chrome launch flag in args.

*Note:* You can retrieve executable and profile paths on the ***chrome://version*** page.

**E.g. (with Windows path examples, see more platforms and more info [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)):**

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
  userDataDir: '%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\AllowCookies'
})
```

or

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false, 
  args: ['--user-data-dir=%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\User Data\\AllowCookies']
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I already tried this, but Chrome does not respect the Preferences file while in headless mode. This is a feature that is not supported at the moment. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4437

Comment: I see. I was tricked by `headless: false` in your code example then  Take a look on this GitHub issue:https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/921, there are some solutions that may work for you to make the flags work in headless mode. I am not aware of other way to set user profile with puppeteer (it doesn't mean there isn't)

Comment: sorry, my error since i was testing. i am now starting the browser in none headless mode. i am now trying to get my profile in there, with the right settings. but it is still not working. I will keep you updated.

Comment: In the end i noticed that Chromium and Chrome handle Cookies quite differently. I now installed Chrome and use it to find alle the Cookies and it works. So i Added the following Code and all the Cookies are listed  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls','--no-sandbox'],
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
 });