# How to access Chrome Downloads elements in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, chromium

Does anyone know to access and interact with items in the Chromes downloads list using Puppeteer?

Everything I've tried doesn't match any elements and returns null.

```
'use strict';

const CHROME_BINARY_PATH = '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: CHROME_BINARY_PATH,
            defaultViewport: null,
            headless: false,
            devtools: false,
            isMobile: false,
            hasTouch: false,
            args: [
                '--window-size=1920,1080',
                '--disable-web-security',
                '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
            ],
            userDataDir: './user_data'
        });
        const page = (await browser.pages())[0]; // load an empty page
        await page.goto('chrome://downloads/',{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 30000 });

        console.log('getting downloads list element');
        await page.waitForSelector('#downloadsList',{ timeout: 5000 });
        let downloadsList = await page.$('#downloadsList');
        console.log(downloadsList);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [puppeteer doesn't open a url without protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090433/puppeteer-doesnt-open-a-url-without-protocol)

Comment: @theDavidBarton - nope, it's opening the URL fine.

Comment: that's good (normally puppeteer doesn't open pages without protocol, like `chrome://` pages). then isn't the download list inside any [shadow root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)? that is a tricky action with puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

This page use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to generate the content, then it is a little hard to query the DOM as normally. But you can use [evaluateHandle](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args)
function to execute a js script on the page, then you can query the `#downloadsList` by this way:

```js
await page.waitForSelector("body > downloads-manager", { timeout: 5000 });
const downloadsList = await page.evaluateHandle(`document.querySelector("body > downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#downloadsList")`);
    console.log(downloadsList);
```

How to get the js snippet?

[image]