# puppeteer doesn't render pages with images URLs without a protocol scheme

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to render html email messages which contains images from urls which do not always contain a protocol scheme.  For example: `<img src="example.com/someimage.jpg" /a>`, the src really should have been `https://example.com/someimage.jpg` or `http://....`

I'm well aware that the url *should* contain a protocol scheme but I don't have control over the html received in the message body of the emails.  Many mail clients such as gmail will render such emails just fine.  I would like to mimic this behavior in puppeteer.

Is there some way in Puppeteer to trap the error and then:

1. try https:// prepended to the href, and failing that
2. try http:// prepended to the href, and failing that
3. then display a broken image?

This is what I do to render the html:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
await page.setContent(htmlEmailBody);
const content = await page.$("body");
const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot({type: "jpeg", omitBackground: true, fullPage: true});
```

This works fine when all the urls have a scheme.  What's the proper way to get this to work when some of the URLs don't always contain the scheme?

This question is related to [puppeteer doesn't open a url without protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090433/puppeteer-doesnt-open-a-url-without-protocol) but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.